# How to retrieve the state of an ApexCharts chart with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

Using ApexCharts with Vue.js.

1. How can I get the state of an ApexCharts chart, for example that one of the data series was disabled or the xy ranges for the current zoom level? In the attached plot this would correspond to the green series being disabled (or the red one being enabled) and x=26:57 and y=731:15623.
2. How can I register events for such changes, like a series being hidden/unhidden, zoom level changed, etc.
3. Can these values be exposed through the Vue model so that they get automatically updated and watchers triggered?

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Are you not using vue-apexcharts?

Comment: Yes, I am using vue-apexcharts.

Comment: I did research and I did search. Sorry, the comment is really not helping, it's rather spamming. Minimum reproducible example of not exposing/documenting an API...?